# How do I add images in pager for views nivo slider?

Tags: 7, views

I am using [Views Nivo Slider](https://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider) for displaying a slideshow of banner images on my site. And i wish to show the pager in the form of images. I tried using Image pager in views slideshow and it worked there. But there are no settings specific to adding an image preset for it. I was able to add numbers instead of bullet. Please suggest a way to add image particularly.

Comment: Please edit the question to add what you've already tried, what didn't work, etc. Requests for tutorials aren't appropriate for this site, you need to show the effort you've made to solve the problem yourself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The module(views Nivo slider) does not support using images as pagers by default. If you want such functionality you would have to write a custom module to extend the views nivo slider module. So I would advise you to go back to using the [views slideshow module](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to achieve that. Even the original plugin created by nivo slider itself does not support such functionality. [See demo site](http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/)

Comment: Thanx i am using views slideshow module as it dint work with Nivo Slideshow